# How to hold the checkbox params in rails after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The search is working fine but the problem is that when i print the excel report according to the result.it is showing all the values in the database, filter is not working.Realoding all over the page, then Checkbox true values are gone. How to hold the params after refreshing the page

```
   .row
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]","CUS", false
              = label_tag "Organizational Customer"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "SUP", false, class: "first_resolution"
              = label_tag "Organzational Supplier"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDCUS", false, class: "first_resolution"
              = label_tag "Individual Customer"
            .col-md-3
              = check_box_tag "search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code][]", "INDSUP", false, class: "first_resolution"
              = label_tag "Individual Supplier"
```

This is my controller,

```
    if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

      search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]
      if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
        organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
        organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
        anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
        search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
      end
      params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?

      @all_address = params[:all_address].to_bool if params[:all_address].present?
      customer_report = params[:search_customer_supplier].map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" if v.present? }.compact
    else
      customer_report = ["accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code:(CUS OR SUP OR INDCUS OR INDSUP)"]
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use check for the submitted value on the third param:

```
check_box_tag 'search_customer_supplier[accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code]', 'CUS', params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] == 'CUS'
```

Comment: It gave me an error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can i use params.dig method like below to hold the value of param 
```
= label_tag "Account No:"



= text_field_tag "search_customer_supplier[account.account_no]", params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'account.account_no'), class: "form-control", placeholder: "Account No"
```

Comment: Yes, try with `#dig`. Should be okay.

Comment: **params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code') == "CUS" **
It was done.Thanks a lot

Comment: But it doesn't hold only one checkbox value.when selecting two or together it doesn't hold the params

Answer (score 0):

After that i aroused another problem when i paginate into 2nd page.

This is the output when it paginate to the next pages.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MDpq.png

Below i mentioned the code(in controller),i think it'd be the query that called.when paginating.

```
 params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?
```