# How to hold the checkbox true value in rails after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The search is working fine but the problem is that when i print the excel report according to the result.it is showing all the values in the database, filter is not working then Checkbox true values are gone. How to hold the 'All address' checkbox params after refreshing the page.

This is my view

```
.col-md-3.small_scale_margin-top2
  = check_box_tag "all_address"
  = label_tag "Show All Addresses"
```

This is my controller

```
    if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

      search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]

      if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
        organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
        organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
        anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
        search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
      end
      #puts "======================================================================"
      # puts params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

      params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'] = params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].join(" OR ") if params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code'].present?

      # puts params[:search_customer_supplier]['accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code']

      customer_report = params[:search_customer_supplier].map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v}" if v.present? }.compact
    else
      customer_report = ["accounts_dealer_types.dealer_code:(CUS OR SUP OR INDCUS OR INDSUP)"]
    end

    @all_address = params[:all_address].to_bool if params[:all_address].present?
    refined_query += customer_report.join(" AND ")
    params[:query] = refined_query
    # params[:per_page] = 500
    @customer_reports = Organization.search(params)

    puts "========================================================="
      puts @customer_reports
    puts "========================================================="

    @account_managers = User.where(active: true)
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:excel_report].present?
        request.format = "xls"
        format.xls { set_attachment_name "customer_supplier_report.xls" }
      else
        format.html
      end
    end

  end
```

In my controller this is the relevant part for the checkbox

```
@all_address = params[:all_address].to_bool if params[:all_address].present?
```

Comment: my version is 

ruby-2.3.8@rails_4_2_1

Sorry um new to ruby on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@all_address` to set the `checked` attribute of [`check_box_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

```
 = check_box_tag "all_address", "1", @all_address
```

Note: Because the `checked` attribute is the third attribute in the list, you must provide a second attribute too. The `"1"` is just the default that would be used for the second argument anyway.

Comment: But it doesn't hold only one checkbox value.when selecting two or together it doesn't hold the params

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. How can `params[:all_address]` hold multiple values? How does `params[:all_address]` look like in the console?

Comment: Oh um sorry,I asked regarding another problem that i already posted here..Can u go through this.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133786/how-to-hold-the-checkbox-params-in-rails-after-search ]

Comment: Can u provide me a solution for that?